# Why it is throwing compile time error?

Tags: exception

Why this program throwing compile time error even though I have declared Ari class which extends Exception class.It is giving me output like "unreported exception Ari; must be caught or declared to be thrown".

```
 class Ari extends Exception{ }
 public class Main
 {  
      public static void main(String [] args) 
      {
          try 
          {
           badMethod();  
           System.out.print("A"); 
          }  
         catch (Exception ex) 
         {
          System.out.print("B");  
         } 
         finally 
         {
          System.out.print("C   "); 
         } 
         System.out.print("D"); 
      }  
     public static void badMethod() 
     {
      throw new Ari(); /* Line 22 */
     }   
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like Java, which uses "checked exceptions".  Since your method can throw an `Ari` exception (in fact, it's *guaranteed to*), the method signature must declare this:

```
public static void badMethod() throws Ari {
    throw new Ari();
}
```

This advises consuming code of the possibility of this specific exception so that it can be written to handle that exception.